# Please correct me where I am wrong in this prove of convexity?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have following function which I am trying to prove is convex $$f(\|\textbf{x}\|,y)=\frac{\|\textbf{x}\|^2}{y}$$ where $\textbf{x}$ is a two dimensional vector and $y\geq 0$. To show that $f(\|\textbf{x}\|,y)$ is convex I introduce a new vector $\textbf{z}=[\|\textbf{x}\|,y]$ and try to show that the following is true $$f(\lambda\textbf{z}_1+(1-\lambda)\textbf{z}_2)-\lambda f(\textbf{z}_1)-(1-\lambda)f(\textbf{z}_2)\leq0$$ where $\textbf{z}_i=[\|\textbf{x}\|_i,y_i]$. After doing some calculation I have following result for $f(\lambda\textbf{z}_1+(1-\lambda)\textbf{z}_2)-\lambda f(\textbf{z}_1)-(1-\lambda)f(\textbf{z}_2)$ $$-2y_1y_2\lambda^2\|\textbf{x}\|_1\|\textbf{x}\|_2-y_1y_2\|\textbf{x}\|_2^2-\lambda \left[(1-\lambda)y_2^2\|\textbf{x}\|_1^2+(1-\lambda)y_1^2\|\textbf{x}\|_2^2-2y_1y_2\|\textbf{x}\|_1\|\textbf{x}\|_2\right]$$ As we can see the first two terms are negative but how to show that the third term is also negative? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Please also point if this method of proving convexity is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The third term need not be negative: just put $\lambda =1$ to get a positive value.  You need a  more sophisticated argument than just looking at each term separately.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for your comment. Actually if i replace $2y_1y_2\|\textbf{x}\|_1\|\textbf{x}\|_2$ by $2y_1y_2\|\textbf{x}\|_1\|\textbf{x}\|_2(1-\lambda +\lambda)$ then it is possible to show that the whole sum is negative or zero. Therefore, it is solved. I am interested in the surrogate function question which you answered a little while ago. Can you please answer to my comment on that question. I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if $f(u,y) = u^2/y$ is convex for $u,y \in [0,\infty)$.
The Hessian at $(u,y)$ is
$$\frac{2}{y}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -u/y \\ -u/y & u^2/y^2\end{bmatrix}.$$
It suffices to check that this is positive semidefinite.
This can be done by [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) (checking that all principal minors are nonnegative).

Comment: But what about the method that I used in my post (specially the use of new variable $\textbf{z}=[\|\textbf{x}\|,y]$)? Is it correct? Further I have one query. Is it always OK to replace the norms with some dummy variable which can only take positive values (like you have used $u$ instead of $\|\textbf{x}\|$ )?